# How to Authenticate Auto Renewable Subscription without Internet Connection using RevenueCat

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I know it is recommended to use the `Purchases.shared.purchaserInfo` method to authenticate subscriptions throughout your app but how about when the user is not connected to the internet.

What would be the recommended way to validate a user who is not connected to the internet when using RevenueCat?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `purchaserInfoWithCompletionBlock` method will read from a cache first so is safe to call even without an internet connection.

Source:  https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-ios/blob/d8282e7c5db2f9b84ca432c1f3d09c28457f00bd/Purchases/Public/RCPurchases.m#L381

Comment: Ah cool, thanks a lot for the clarification. I'm liking RevenueCat more and more.